# IVP using system of equations: Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, initial-value-problems

The given equations and values are
$$x^{"}=-5x+2y\space(1)$$
$$y^{"}=2x-8y \space(2)$$
$$x(0)=10 \space,x^{'}(0)=13$$
$$y(0)=5 \space ,y^{'}(0)=-16$$
Rewriting $(1)$ and $(2)$
$$(D^2+5)x-2y=0 \space (1)$$
$$(D^2+8)y-2x=0\space (2)$$
Finding the roots is easy, operate $(1)$ by $(D^2+8)$ and multiplying $(2)$ by $2$ and adding the two equations yields:
$$(D^4+13D^2+36)x=0$$
$$m^4+13m^2+36=0$$
$$(m^2+4)(m^2+9)=0$$
$$m_{1,2}=\pm2i$$
$$m_{3,4}=\pm3i$$
Then the Aux. equation is:
$$x(t)=C_1\cos(2t)+C_2\sin(2t)+C_3\cos(3t)+C_4\sin(3t)$$ 
Now, because we are given initial values in terms of both $x$ and $y$ we can assume that we need $y(t)$, which is:
$$y(t)=C_5\cos(2t)+C_6\sin(2t)+C_7\cos(3t)+C_8\sin(3t)$$
From the given we can tell we need to take the 2nd derivative of $x(t)$:
$$x^{'}(t)=-4C_1\cos(2t)-4C_2\sin(2t)-9C_3\cos(3t)-9C_4\sin(3t)$$
Now from here we use $(1)$ to get rid of the excess constants:
$$x^{"}+5x-2y=0$$
What I got was:
$$\frac{1}{2}C_{1,2}=C_{5,6}$$
$$-2C_{3,4}=C_{7,8}$$
But when I plugged in for my IV's I got:
$$y(0)=5: 5=\frac{1}{2}C_1-2C_3$$
and thats where I stopped because I think I messed something serious up.
Am I wrong and my math is correct?

Comment: +1 What you have observed is correct and true $\frac{1}{2}C_{1,2}=C_{5,6}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct:
$$10=C_1+C_3$$
$$13=2C_2+3C_4$$
Now we need two more equations from intital condition on $y$:
$$x''+5x=2y$$
$$x''(0)=-5x(0)+2y(0)$$
$$x''(0)=-50+10=-40$$
$$x(t)=C_1\cos(2t)+C_2\sin(2t)+C_3\cos(3t)+C_4\sin(3t)$$
$$x''(0)=-4C_1-9C_3=-40$$
And a fourth equation:
$$x'''(0)=-5x'(0)+2y'(0)$$
$$x'''(0)=-5*13+2*(-16)=-97$$
$$x'''(0)=-8C_2-27C_4=-97$$
You have four equations. You can solve the system for the $C_i$ and deduce $y(t)$ too.
$$
\begin{align}
8C_2+27C_4=&97 \\
4C_1+9C_3=&40 \\
C_1+C_3=&10 \\
2C_2+3C_4=&13
\end{align}
$$
For $y(t)$ you have:
$$2y(t)=x''+5x$$
$$2y(t)=C_1\cos(2t)+C_2\sin(2t)-4C_3\cos(3t)-4C_4\sin(3t)$$
I find for the coefficients:
$$(C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4)=(10,2,0,3)$$
Therefore we have :
$$\boxed {y(t)=5\cos(2t)+\sin(2t)-6\sin(3t) \\
x(t)=10\cos(2t)+2\sin(2t)+3\sin(3t)}
$$